# App storeへのRealm使用アプリの申請の際のスキーマバージョンについて

Tags: swift, ios, realm

App StoreにあがってるアプリはRealmを初めて使ったままのスキーマ定義なのでスキーマは変更しておりません。それゆえ、configやスキーマバージョンも書いておりません。

スキーマ定義を変更する必要が出たので今回ローカル上でスキーマのバージョンを上げてマイグレーション処理を行ったりと色々試行錯誤しましたがうまくいかなく、Simulatorで一度アプリを削除してバージョンを０にしたところビルドもマイグレーションもできました。

ただApp store上のアプリは`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`で定義をせずにアプリを申請していたため、次にアプリをアップデートする際には`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`のブロック内にスキーマバージョンを上げて記述し、書かなければならないのですがこの際の値は`0`で問題ないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmのファイルは各ユーザーのデバイスにそれぞれファイルが存在するわけですので、手元でアプリを削除してうまくいってもリリースされたアプリを使うユーザーのデバイスではそうはなりません。すでにそのアプリを利用しているユーザーのデバイスには変更前のスキーマのファイルがあるので、アプリをバージョンアップした際にはスキーマが一致しないので、スキーマバージョンを上げていなければクラッシュします。

まだアプリをAppStoreで配布してなければ、もちろん開発時は自由に試行錯誤できますが、一度リリースしてしまったなら、アップデートでスキーマを変更するならスキーマバージョンも合わせて上げる必要があります。

ただし、既存のデータを消してしまってもいいのであれば、`Realm.RealmConfiguration.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded`プロパティを使うと、マイグレーションが必要な場合は自動的に既存のファイルを消して作り直すということを自動的にやってくれます。

スキーマバージョン0から1のマイグレーション時はデータ削除、1から2のマイグレーション時はデータ移行をする、としたい場合は、私なら下記のように書きます。条件に応じて`deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded`プロパティを切り替える方法よりも意図が明確になります。

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 2, migrationBlock: { (migration, schemaVersion) in
    if schemaVersion < 1 {
        migration.deleteData(forType: "ModelA")
        migration.deleteData(forType: "ModelB")
        migration.deleteData(forType: "ModelC")
    }
    if schemaVersion < 2 {
        migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: "ModelA") { (newObject, oldObject) in
            ...
        }
        migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: "ModelB") { (newObject, oldObject) in
            ...
        }
        migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: "ModelC") { (newObject, oldObject) in
            ...
        }
    }
})
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。一点疑問です。アプリをgit管理しているのですが`deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` の記述はgit管理する必要はありますでしょうか。app storeへアプリを提出する際にのみ書くべきでしょうか。また、以前のデータを消去した後、またアップデートをする際に`deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` を書くのをやめることで既存データが消えなくすることは可能でしょうか。お手数ですがご回答頂ければ幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: それはアプリケーションの仕様によります。アップデートの際にデータ構造の変更があるかどうか、ある場合にデータを移行せず消して作り直すのであればdel‌​eteRealmIfMigrationN‌​eededを使用します。そのバージョンでdel‌​eteRealmIfMigrationN‌​eededを使用したということは当然バージョン管理されるべきでしょう。
あとからdel‌​eteRealmIfMigrationN‌​eededを消すことができるかどうかですが、それは場合によります。なぜならアプリを使っている人全員がアプリを更新するとは限らないからです。なので以前はdel‌​eteRealmIfMigrationN‌​eededを使っていたが、それをやめる場合は古いバージョンから更新されることも考慮したマイグレーションを書く必要があります。データの移行がなければスキーマバージョンをあげるだけなのでそれほど難しくはありません。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。すると、例えば今回はdel‌​eteRe‌​almIfMigrationN‌​eed‌​edを用いて、その後のアップデートで新しく以前のデータを消して作ったDBを消したくない場合にはバージョンによって処理を条件分岐させると言うことで大丈夫でしょうか？

Comment: まあ理屈ではそうです。ただそうするより普通のマイグレーションを書いた方がシンプルに書けると思いますよ。あまりそういう条件分岐はしません。コメントでやり取りするのは限界があるので、何をやりたいのかを現在のコードと一緒に新しい質問として投稿してもらう方が役にたつ回答ができると思います。

Comment: やりたいこととしては非常にシンプルなのですが、カラムを追加してなおかつ既存のカラムからデータを移行させたくない次第です。それゆえ、一旦以前のデータを削除させたいので通常のマイグレーションは該当しないかと思われます。

Comment: 回答に追記しましたので参考にしてください。本来は別の質問にしていただいた方がStackOverflowの仕組み上はよかったです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。大変参考になりました。今後もRealmを使用させていただきます。